# How should I control the time and temperature when baking two dishes?

Tags: meat, oven, temperature, cooking-time, potatoes

I want to cook multiple dishes at the same time using a conventional oven. A 9x 13 pan with potatoes should bake in an oven of 350 degrees F for 45 minutes. The other dish, a ham, should be in a 325 degree F oven for about 2 hours and 15 minutes.

How long can the potato dish be cooked for at 325? Any help would be appreciated. This will be done for Sunday dinner while at church. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The ham should rest for at least 15 minutes after cooking, and probably longer than that.  So you could put the potatoes into the oven when the ham has 20 or 25 minutes remaining, and then when you take the ham out, increase the temperature to 350-375F and continue cooking the potatoes while the ham rests for 15-20 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I would put your oven at 325 for both. Put in the ham and after 1 hour 15 minutes, put in the other dish. Let them bake together for about an hour.

I wouldn't recommended doing this while you're not at home, but that's your own choice.

Answer (score 0):

The ham can also be cooked at 300. For about 3 hours.  If you cook it in a closed container a little over cooking shouldn't cause any problem there.  At 300 you will probably need about 1:20 but if it has to be in for 1:30 it should not be overdone.